# No problem executing foreign key query with misspelled column names

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, wamp, wampserver

Dears ,

I have a WAMP server installed on my PC, the Foreign key doesn't work at all on MySQL

I use the following code:

`ALTER TABLE table2 ADD FOREIGN KEY (column_name) REFERENCES table1(primary_column);`

The above query execute successfully even if you misspelled the column names...

Example: if i write the query as below, it execute with no problems !

`ALTER TABLE table2 ADD FOREIGN KEY (fshajdsa) REFERENCES table1(dsssadsf);`

And if i spelled the columns correctly it executes with no problem also, but the foreign key doesn't work.

WAMP Version: 3.7.1
MySQL Version: 5.7.24

I tried to search on a problem as same as mine on the internet and couldn't find any.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I am not sure what this question is about - are you looking for a way of trapping badly formed attempts to create FKs in a wamp environment? MYSQL will spot the types of error you have - so are you failing to catch errors in php?

Comment: what is the storage engine of the table?

Comment: what does the message shows when you execute wrong query.. can you share the screenshot in question?

Comment: @spyker I tried to create the relation using the MySQL designer page and they showed me an error saying "error relational features are disabled", i have searched the error on the internet and found that it's related to the table engine as you have mentioned, it was MyISAM and it should be InnoDB. Thanks so much all for replying.

Answer (score 0):

It's related to the table engine, it should be InnoDB.

`ALTER TABLE my_table ENGINE = InnoDB;`